# libext2fs code not working

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ext2

I just tried to access my superblock information using the code as shown here:-
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/340724/

However, I get the error as shown here:-
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/340723/

My kernel version is 2.6.31-22-generic and I have not installed any libraries/additional kernel headers for the same. The OS is Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
```

to the top of your source code.